# Need clarification on switching CiviCRM hosting from a host/consultant

Tags: import

We are currently hosting with a company that also assists us with are CIVI Crm. We are interested in moving our site to a new host and would like to know if the CIVI will move with it? Without having in-depth knowledge of the "back-end" of Joomla/CIVI... I would like to speak with a representative to get a clear understanding of how we can continue to use CiVI and yet obtain a new hosting company. Please, could somebody call me and help us through this transition? Thank you, Tacey Martinek-978-772-2787

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can move your Civi installation to new hosting (though it is recommended to use a knowledgeable/experienced provider to do so; and you sound like you are on board with that idea). A good place to start is with one of the providers listed here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Here is some background on those providers listed and some tips on selecting a new provider: https://civicrm.org/about-service-providers

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is a crowd-sourced open source software, which means that there is no company with representatives to call you back and talk through these things unless you hire someone to do so. I recommend removing your phone number from this public post, just as a matter of privacy protection. There are software-as-service companies that do this, www.civisites.com comes to mind.

Who set up your current site? They are probably the best person to talk you through this. If not them, then who is your current host? Your current hosting company should be able to help you move your data to a new hosting company, sometimes for a small fee. Your new hosting company may be able to help you move your civi information and installation as well.

If you have specific troubles in moving your installation, you can post your question on this forum and friendly community members will work to help you out, if they can.